# Div height is not increasing on appending any element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with following CSS:

```
           div
           {
              width:600px;
              height:auto;
           }
```

Now my problem is when i append any element `(like $('div').append(any element))` in this div its height is not increasing accordingly. Whats the problem?

**EDIT**

The element which i am appending has `height:auto`. And the div in which i am appending has empty.

Comment: are the elements inside this `div` set to `float`?

Comment: can you create an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: can you put the last element with style `clear: both;` ?

Comment: I bet it is inheriting some attributes which conflict with the auto height

Comment: I'm not familiar with jQuery, but shouldn't you apply the code to a div id, instead of 'div' itself??!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QTcmY/ - seems to be OK

Comment: @poepje: It's not jQuery code, it's a CSS rule.

Comment: `(like $('div').append(any element))` is not CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with that code. The `auto` value is the default for a div, so (assuming that there is no other style applying to the element) it's the same as just:

```
div { width: 600px; }
```

So, there is nothing that is limiting the height of the div in that code. You have to look elsewhere in your code to find something that affects the element.

Some browsers let you inspect an element, which shows you exactly what CSS applies to it. I use the Firebug plugin in Firefox for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no issue with the code. Here's my example two ways.

1. onload append element http://jsfiddle.net/VnLtv/
2. on click of div add elem http://jsfiddle.net/VnLtv/1/

Make sure that your code is in a `$(document).ready` or equivalent `$(function(){`